# How to test NgRx selector which uses props?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have the following selector:

```
export const selectTableById = createSelector(selectRestaurantState, (state: RestaurantState, props) =>
  state.tables.find((table) => table.id === props.id)
);
```

Which uses the props to add additional information to the selctor when calling it.

In unit test i am trying something like this:

```
  it("should ...", () => {
    expect(selectTableById.projector(state, { props: { id: "id" } })).toEqual(...);
  });
```

but i have not found info about how to call the projector function with props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
const tables = ...
const state = <RestaurantState>{ tables };

it("should select table matched by id from props", () => {
    const props = { id: "t2" };
    expect(selectTableById.projector(state, props)).toEqual(tables[1]);
});
```

My problem was that, i added the wrong state (the whole appstate rather than just the restaurant state) to the projector funciton, and the props was badly formatted.